# What is the Greek version of $\;\cal{quod~erat~demonstrandum}\;$?

Tags: terminology, math-history

What is the Greek version of "*quod erat demonstrandum*"?

**Edit**:

> $\quad$The symbol $\square$ will denote the end of a proof; it may be read as "Q.E.D." abbreviating the Latin *quod erat demonstrandum,* which translates the Greek of Euclid of Alexandria "ὅπερ ἔδει δεῖξαι".

I found this in *Bridge to Abstract Mathematics*, but I was hoping to find something I could actually copy and paste into a tex file.

Comment: From what I know, Euclid was the first to use it.

Comment: Just FYI, [Latin squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square) have nothing to do with the symbol $\square$.

Comment: I know, but maybe Latin square people know Latin, and many of the people that I know that know Latin also know Greek. I learned Latin, but I never learned Greek. I think it's cute that you think that I thought there was a strong connection.

Comment: How did whoever edited the image do what the did?

Comment: @Trancot just cutting and uploading the edited image.

Comment: Oh, I thought were was a native crop feature.

Comment: If your question is "How do I enter *ὅπερ ἔδει δεῖξαι* in a TeX file?", you should ask it on http://tex.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 11):

[It originates from the Greek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.):  hóper édei deîxai (ὅπερ ἔδει δεῖξαι), meaning "which had to be demonstrated". So the Latin Q.E.D. is a variation on the translation of the the expression used by the Greeks, namely, we know it was used by Euclid and Archimedes, and likely other Greek scholars who followed "suit."

Further clarification in the Wikipedia entry is truer to Euclid's use of the expression:

> Since the verb "δείκνυμι" also means to show or to prove, a better translation from the Greek would read, "what was required to be proved."

Added: See also [Earliers Known Uses of Mathematical Terms](http://jeff560.tripod.com/q.html).

Comment: @amWhy: Working on your Greek I see! :-) +1

Answer (score 3):

"ὅπερ ἔδει δεῖξαι" was used by Euclid and Archimedes.

- Wikipedia

Comment: That doesn't compile in French font mode... +_+

Comment: @Trancot I didn't know why :( probably your browser can't display it.

Answer (score 2):

Further to all the above, you can usually find it as ο.ε.δ. (short form of "ὅπερ ἔδει δεῖξαι").